# パスワード認証を実装したい

Tags: swift, ios, firebase

Firebaeドキュメントに記載されている以下の内容について、
３の言っている意味は分かるのですが、具体的に何をすれば良いのかが分かりません。
４については、クロージャーをしてるんだな〜程度には理解できるのですが、これをAppDelegateのどこに記載したら良いのかが分かりません。

参考URL：
[iOS でパスワード ベースのアカウントを使用して Firebase 認証を行う](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/password-auth?hl=ja)

> 3. 新しいユーザーがアプリの登録フォームを使用して登録したら、アプリで必要な新しいアカウントの検証手順（新しいアカウントのパスワードが正しく入力されていることや、パスワードの複雑さの要件を満たしているかの確認など）を行います。
> 4. 新しいユーザーのメールアドレスとパスワードを `createUserWithEmail:email:password:completion:` に渡して、新しいアカウントを作成します。
>
> ```
> Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
> // ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

> ３の言っている意味は分かるのですが、具体的に何をすれば良いのかが分かりません

意味を誤解しておられるので、「何をすれば良いのかが分かりません」になってしまっているのではないでしょうか？

> 3. 新しいユーザーがアプリの登録フォームを使用して登録したら、アプリで必要な新しいアカウントの検証手順（新しいアカウントのパスワードが正しく入力されていることや、パスワードの複雑さの要件を満たしているかの確認など）を行います。

「フォーム」と言うのは色々な意味に使われますが、ここでは「入力画面」の意味です。つまりアプリにユーザ登録の画面を用意し、ユーザがメアドやらパスワードやらを入力して「登録する」ボタンを押したら、(4.に行く前に)「アプリで必要な新しいアカウントの検証手順」を行え、と言っているわけです。

> ４については、クロージャーをしてるんだな〜程度には理解できるのですが、これをAppDelegateのどこに記載したら良いのかが分かりません

上記のようなわけですから、「AppDelegateのどこに記載」するのではなく、ユーザ登録画面の「登録する」ボタンの処理の一部として記述します。

---

実際にはさらに具体的にどうすれば良いのかと言った情報を見たいかもしれませんが、細部はあなたがこれから作ろうとしているシステム・アプリの内容にもよるので、できる限り自分で調べて見てください。

「アプリの登録フォーム」と言うのが、アプリ内に存在するユーザ登録画面だと言うことが理解できれば、ユーザ登録画面の存在するFirebaseのサンプルアプリを見つけられるだろうと思います。

それでもわからない点は残るかもしれませんが、ご自身でここまではやってみた、と言うコードを含めた上でわからない点を質問されると、できるだけそのコードに沿った形で回答をつけてみようという方が出てくるだろうと思います。